# How to conditionally run tests in cucumber

Tags: tags, cucumber, conditional-statements

Having done a bit of research on this question, I see it's been asked before. The answer always seems to be along the lines of "if you need to conditionally skip a test, you're doing something wrong." I'm new to Cucumber and programming in general, so I'm hoping someone has a suggestion as to how to get around my current dilemma.

All new features that are developed by our team are put behind a feature flag and turned on per environment when they are ready, ie, they are always on in dev, usually on in test, sometimes on in integration, and only on in staging and prod when we think they are ready to ship.

I am aware of the tagging feature and think this could be a solution for me except for a couple of things. One, there are lots of features and they are flipped on and off in various environments often. Unless I'm totally on top of things, I'm going to miss whether or not I need to change a specific feature tag. The other issue is that I'm working in a shared test codebase and our tagging system is not currently setup per environment. Although I could start lobbying for this change, it is not likely to happen in the short term and, for the previously given reason, I'm not sure I'd be happy with that solution.

What I'd ideally like to do is use the feature flag and code something along the lines of "If flag X is true, then run this test, otherwise do nothing." However, I haven't been able to find a "do nothing" method. I have set some of the tests up to do "pending" if the flag is not set, but I'd prefer to have the test not run at all if the flag is not set. Pending makes it look like I have a bunch of incomplete test cases which is simply not true.

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You could just tag each scenario with the environments that it should be run on, and then just use that tag when you call cucumber.

Answer (score 0):

An possible solution would be to put a tag for all of the tests for each feature then write a launch script which goes through the project, checks each flag, then passes the associated tag into cucumber.

In ruby this would look something like:

```
cuke_cmd = "cucumber --tags @essential
flags.each do |flag|
  if getFlagState(flag) # code which checks if the flag is true
    cuce_cmd += ","+getFlagTag(flag) # getFlagTag returns the associated tag in the format @flag
  end
end
system(cuke_cmd)
```

in this @essential tags would be applied to anything which would always be run and each additional feature would have a tag associated with it.

You will then want to go through all the possible flags and append the associated tag to the command.

At the end of this the program would execute passing the tags for each feature that had the flag set to true.